# Trying to load Pear on Windows XP Professional

Tags: php, windows-xp, pear

When I start go_pear.php I get (after about 15%)

```
Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.7.0\php\go-pear.php on line 1414
Starting installation ...
Loading zlib: ok

Bootstrapping Installer...................
Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

An Exception Has Occurred

Unknown location: /pear/pear-core/branches/PEAR_1_4/PEAR.php

HTTP Response Status
404 Not Found

ok
Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote)
Fatal error: Class 'PEAR' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.7.0\php\temp\Archive\Tar.php on line 58
```

So where do I go from her?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ´go-pear.php` but download http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar and install PEAR using that.